# Does giving money to the poor perpetuate homelessness?

Tags: social-policy

Some people say that giving money to the person you see on the side of the road begging for change actually helps that person continue staying on the road begging for change.

Some people say panhandling yields significantly more income than most people make by working.

Have there been any studies on this?

Some apply the same reasoning to deny that public funds should go towards the homeless. Is there any validity to this argument?

Comment: Starting point: there are studies that suggest that homeless people are more likely to have drug addictions, and thus giving direct cash to them is essentially enabling those who are drug addicts to continue their addiction.

Comment: This seems like a better question for [economics.se].

Comment: @jwodder: Homelessness and what to do about homelessness is current public policy issue in most large cities in the U.S.

Comment: As this is asking about giving to panhandlers rather than the direction of public funds to homeless people, I agree that this is not a good fit for the politics SE. What does this have to do with politics?

Comment: @Avi: Does the edit adequately address your concern?

Comment: "Some people say" just isn't a great source for us to fact check.

Comment: This isn't really a question about politics. The question does not imply that you are a politician or that the homeless person you give to is one. Private donations to private people are not a political process. What *might* be on-topic is asking about the effect of **government-sponsored welfare** on homeless people. So if you rewrite the question to primarily focus on this aspect (instead of just tangentially), then it might be worth reopening.

Comment: @Philipp, Re *"Private donations to private people"*: in my view, the homeless are *anything but* private people -- they're involuntarily public, as is begging.  In a sense the homeless are politicians by default, who, just like regular politicians, campaign for issues, solicit the public for funds, and may sometimes fail to use those funds wisely, or as promised.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, Re *"Starting Point"*: this assumes that the functions those drugs serve are usually a *bad thing*.  Many ordinary citizens who take pain medication are wrecks or will go haywire without it.  It seems as though you're saying that we should expect or demand greater temperance and fortitude from the homeless.  Some argue that even supporting the habit of some homeless addict may prevent worse crimes inspired by their inability to afford their drug.

Comment: Here is a well described study done in Toronto streets https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC121964/ . It answers in one given context. The situation may be very different with for instance panhandling in touristic places for dollars or euros in a country with a very weak currency.

Comment: @RainWillow I don't think it does, it just confuses the issue further. If you want to ask about publicly funded wealth transfer programs, then that's a good, relevant question. But right now you seem to be asking primarily about panhandling, which isn't on-topic, and then connect that in some unclear way to politics.

Comment: @Avi: If the OP question is off-topic, [then why is this question on-topic](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/15907/5971)? I will post this comment in meta if it's a better fit there. But I'm curious about your opinion.

Comment: @RainWillow That question is entirely about public policy, specifically, whether the government should build more highways.

Comment: @Avi: In your latest comment, if you replace the words "build more highways" with "give public funds to the homeless," wouldn't your same reasoning apply to the OP question?

Comment: @RainWillow No, because OP is primarily asking about whether it's a good idea that private individuals give money to homeless people, and what the effects of that are.

Comment: @RainWillow the confusion is that your question isn't clear that you are asking primarily about government programs helping the homeless. That is a more valid question, but ultimately a much more complex question. Essentially, you're asking us to simply rebut a lazy "some people say" argument that is often used. It's not a bad question, but is rather broad.

Comment: You may be interested in the 'welfare queen' argument. It falls into that "some people say..." line of arguing where the exception to the norm is pulled out and implied as being that actual norm when no evidence can back it up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welfare_queen

Answer (score 1):

I think that totally denying public funds to the homeless is far from being feasible as it is part of *[social security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_security)*, which in turn is part of the Universal Declaration of Human Rights:

> Everyone, as a member of society, has the right to social security and
>   is entitled to realization, through national effort and international
>   co-operation and in accordance with the organization and resources of
>   each State, of the economic, social and cultural rights indispensable
>   for his dignity and the free development of his personality.

Social security/protection is also part of the [Inclusive growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusive_growth) concept.

From a layman perspective (as I understand it): we do not plan for letting people die in the streets. We do something about it.

"Some people say panhandling yields significantly more income than most people make by working."

Although I have heard about such rumors, I think this is highly exaggerated in most of the cases (at least within Western countries). The first answers from [here](https://www.quora.com/Homelessness-How-much-money-do-beggars-panhandlers-make-an-hour) provide references related to income and expenses of beggars. One particular study is [this](http://www.cmaj.ca/content/167/5/477.full.pdf+html) and its conclusion is the following:

> [..] Toronto-centric study considers both numbers, and it concludes
>   that the majority of Toronto's beggars live in extreme poverty and are
>   homeless.

The same article explains the complexity of the phenomena and suggests that it is not only the financial dimension:

> The homeless often need something more than money. They need money and
>   direction. For most homeless people, direction means a job and a roof.
>   A 1999 study from HUD polled homeless people about what they needed
>   most: 42% said help finding a job; 38% said finding housing; 30% said
>   paying rent or utilities; 13% said training or medical care.

[This article](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2011/03/should-you-give-money-to-homeless-people/72820/) deals with the question from the title and its conclusion is the following:

> The short answer is no [, we should not give money to homeless people]. The  long answer is yes, but only if you work for an organization that can ensure the money is spent wisely.

[This article](http://www.businessinsider.com/this-state-may-be-the-first-to-end-homelessness-for-good-2015-2) deals with a success story related to homelessness and confirms that a more complex approach (not just financial aid) gives the best results:

> Initially, critics feared Utah would lose tons of money by giving the
>   homeless permanent housing, and that doing so would just "incentivize
>   mooching," as Minhaj put it. However, state officials found Housing
>   First actually saving the government money over time, especially as it
>   encourages people to become more self-sufficient sooner.
>
> Moreover, Housing First homes are not free: New tenants have to pay
>   $50 or 30% of their income to rent each month (whichever amount is
>   greater).
>
> Between shelters, jail stays, ambulances, and hospital visits, caring
>   for one homeless person typically costs the government $20,000 a year.
>   Providing one homeless person with permanent housing, however — as
>   well as a social worker to help them transition into mainstream
>   society — costs the state $8,000, The New Yorker reported in
>   September.

**"Is there any validity to this argument?"**

Clearly, taking care in any form about the homeless incur costs and I find the only reasonable argument for denying public funds. But, as already illustrated, careful spending can provide good results.

So, yes, there is some validity, but I would say a little one.

Comment: If the question was reworeded to state 'joblessness' instead of 'homelessness' (something, in many instances, given to people to the poor for free).  It would be 100% valid.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welfare_trap

Answer (score -4):

Now, I'm just gonna go out on a limb and say 'probably not'.
I got no hard numbers, but till someone brings any up, allow me to use theory to back up my claim, and provide you with at least some sort of answer:

1. If it did, wouldn't all the people living 'paycheck to paycheck' catch onto this novel new industry at some point? Thus, flooding the market? Making the local news at least once?
2. If this practice were happening, and was so consistent as to be a issue, wouldn't a catchy name be coined for it by now?
3. Wouldn't the politicians pushing this idea jump at the chance to push the statistics in your face 24/7 to prove their point?
4. Wouldn't its effectiveness vary wildly? Place to place? Time of day? Weather? People's charitable feelings?
5. If this were happening, why are there still so many homeless people whom, despite being in a industry that pays more then McDonald's, still live on the streets, and not periodically 'disappear' to go off and enjoy their hard-earned cash.
6. If they spend their money, wouldn't there be records? Couldn't that be used as proof? Wouldn't that potentially be used to bring tax evasion charges upon these so called 'homeless people'?
7. If this is so profitable, why are there poor people who aren't busy doing this all day? What are they gaining by sitting their all day looking all hopeless and whatnot?

So ya, I can see the down votes now. I think this claim is utter bullocks, a straw-man, nothing more. Hope you at least thought this a neat read lad.

Comment: So.... you write a poor answer, knowing its poor... yet still write it because...? I'm happy to give you -1/delete vote.

Comment: I never called it poor, I merely described as being more of an anecdote. Whats with this sudden hostility? calling for deletion?

Comment: My apologies, reading it now it does seem sorta silly... but still, I don't get the deletion pate mate.

Comment: Can you back up any of that with actual empiric research? Answers on this website are expected to back up the claims they make and not just say what the author's intuition and personal observations say is correct.

Comment: @Philipp, Tirous's answer seems less intuitive and observational, than argumentative, that is, he's arguing from obvious facts (none that require back up) to general principles (some in accord with obvious facts).  Which has been done by every political author since Aristotle.  His arguments may or may not be sound, but there's nothing wrong with the method.

Comment: @agc none of these facts are really that obvious. For example, in the city where I live we recently had news reports about an organized "beggars cartel" who were turning street begging into a de-facto organized multinational commercial enterprise. That's why we need a "back it up" policy. If you just argument on "obvious facts" without doing any actual research, you might actually be argumenting from a standpoint of misinformation.

Comment: @Philipp, The fact that actual homeless people exist, and that some them beg, is the basis of the question.  Unless we're asserting the radical position that there are absolutely *no* true homeless people out there, the existence of bogus beggars and organized crime is not immediately relevant.   (i.e. there are cartels selling adulterated olive oil, but it doesn't follow from that fact that olive oil itself is a bad thing to buy merely because counterfeits exist.).